# how to make a window prompt message shown when the window is empty and I click ok

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, but I want it to show a text on the browser when I click "OK" but I didn't input anything in the prompt window.

```
var hobby = (prompt("Podaj swoje hobby: "));
if (hobby === null){
alert("Dlaczego nie podałeś swojego hobby?");
document.write("Moje hobby to: ");
}else{
document.write(hobby);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp), in the Technical Details section it's mentioned:

> A String. If the user clicks "OK", the input value is returned. If the user clicks "cancel", null is returned. If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned.

Therefore, if you click Ok with no input, the value will be "", so you can check for it explicitly (this is the recommended approach because it's most specific):

```
if (hobby === ""){ ...
```

Or you could check for a falsy value (which is a common practice in JS):

```
if (!hobby){ ...
```

This will check for any case of no value (null - e.g. user clicked cancel, or empty user clicked OK with no value given). **Use this variant with care though** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be `if (hobby === null || hobby === "")`

Answer (score 0):

> your code is working fine just remove the extra brackets of prompt and provide default value to prompt and on ok click check new value with blank value by comparing it with "":

```
var hobby = prompt("Podaj swoje hobby: ","value");
if (hobby === ""){
alert("Dlaczego nie podałeś swojego hobby?");
document.write("Moje hobby to: ");
}else{
document.write(hobby);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function display_text() {
var hobby = prompt("Podaj swoje hobby: ");
if (hobby == null || hobby == ""){
alert("Dlaczego nie podałeś swojego hobby?");
document.write("Moje hobby to: ");
}else{
document.write(hobby);
}  }
```

```html
<button onclick="display_text()">Click Me</button>
```

Hope this helps.